# What is the easiest method for vertical+horizontal centering of a div in the window?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, alignment

Given a `div` with known dimensions, say `width: 300px; height: 200px`, what is the easiest method to place it in the middle of the screen both vertically and horizontally ? [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wv2jZ/)

I'm interested in latest Firefox (no need for IE hacks).

**CSS only please, no Javascript.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Position it 50% from the window/parent container and use a *negative* margin size that's half of the elements width/height :)**

```
position: absolute; // or fixed if you don't want it scrolling with the page.
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -100px;
```

You might need to set `height: 100%`, on both the `body` and `html`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Edit:** Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wv2jZ/14/) .

Comment: Wouldn't `position: fixed` be more appropriate?

Comment: @sje397, that would depend on whether they want the div to scroll with the page or not.

Comment: @Marco, it seems working without setting `height: 100%` on `html, body`. Why it is needed ?

Comment: @Misha: It's just to ensure that the body element fills the entire window height. It could've been a IE7/IE6 issue but I still tend to write it when I have to center something vertically.

Comment: @Marko. My question is, since you only specify position relative to the left side, won't the Div (on small screens with a Div width of say 1000px) be aligned asymmetrically left and right. That is, there will always be space on the left side, but if the div is bigger than the screen resolution, there won't be any white space on the right side since you only fixed it from the left border?

Comment: @DextrousDave if the screen is smaller than the div then obviously the div will stretch past the viewport. Here's a fiddle if you want to test it. Please note that you could make the div use a percentage based width with percentage margins. http://jsfiddle.net/xXqaV/

Answer (score 1):

Without supporting IE, this is actually pretty easy to achieve using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Here's an update to your HTML:

```
<div id='my_div'>
    <div class="centered">this is vertically centered</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#my_div
{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.centered
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And to preview: http://jsfiddle.net/we8BE/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have 2 height declarations for `#my_div`?

Comment: Ah, good catch. I didn't see you already had a height defined in your styles. That might not be exactly what you're looking for, but a demonstration of how it can be done in a non-IE setting.

Comment: The centred div is 100% height - the original question stated 200px. It doesnt work if you remove the 100% height either (at least not in Chrome). Firefox doesnt run well on my machine so cant test it - I am hoping Chrome behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the simplest way, but it seems to work.

http://www.infinitywebdesign.com/research/cssverticalcentereddiv.htm

Comment: That's using exactly the same solution I am :)

Answer (score 0):

What methods are you open to using? For example CSS up to what level - 2 or 3? Javascript? jQuery? My first thought is that, since divs can be centred horizontally through `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`, maybe try `margin: auto;` for all 4 sides. Let me know if it works.

Comment: CSS -2 or 3? What do you mean @ClarkeyBoy?

Comment: Well I dont know if there is anything available from CSS3 which would help, but if it needs to work in CSS2. I wasnt gonna make the effort to find out if that was the case without knowing whether it can be CSS3 in the first place.

Comment: I mean definitely without Javascript. CSS 3 is fine (as I wrote: latest Firefox). `margin: auto` does not work.

Comment: Ok well I am at a loss. I am currently using the other method, as suggested by Marko originally, because I hit this problem a while back and that was a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest? One of the numerous [jQuery center plugins](http://webdeveloper-blog.blogspot.com/2010/05/jquery-center-plugin-easy-centering.html) available...

Comment: Read the comments on my post - "I mean definitely without Javascript."

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: Ok... that comment was not there when I started writing... No problem!

Comment: This doesn't deserve a down-vote since the original post didn't explicitly say without JS. I'm going to upvote just for that reason :)